# How to specify css selector in beautiful soup and python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, scrapinghub

I am trying to scrape the titles of the cards from this link : https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card

Using the below code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json, requests, re

axis_url = ["https://www.axisbank.com/retail/cards/credit-card"]

html = requests.get(axis_url[0])
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'lxml')

print(soup.select("#ulCreditCard h3"))
```

Output is as follows :

```
[]
```

My main concern is how shall I specify a css selector tag that I got using the selector gadget when it is in this form **#ulCreditCard h3** in the soup.select() function.

Comment: What you are doing is fine for BeautifulSoup, the issue is actually because the site loads the card information dynamically with JavaScript. BeautifulSoup does not execute JavaScript and dynamically update the HTML. If you print out the HTML you get via requests, I bet you won't find the cards, which is why the CSS selectors do not find it. You may have to use something like Selenium that can execute the JS on the HTML, then you should be able to find the content.

Comment: @facelessuser could you write the respective selenium code please!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, the information you are looking for is obtained via Javascript. It uses a slightly different URL to get the JSON data containing all of the card details. If you use this instead, you can easily list all of the card names without needing to use BeautifulSoup. For example:

```
import requests
import json

axis_url = "https://www.axisbank.com/AjaxService/GetCreditCardsProducts"
data = {"strcategory" : "[]", "strrewardtypes" :"[]"}
r = requests.post(axis_url, data=data)

for entry in json.loads(r.json()[0]):
    print(entry['Name'])
```

Would give you the following cards:

```
Axis Bank ACE Credit Card
Axis Bank AURA Credit Card
Privilege Easy Credit Card
Axis Bank Reserve Credit Card
Axis Bank Freecharge Plus Credit Card
IndianOil Axis Bank Credit Card
Axis Bank Magnus Credit Card
Flipkart Axis Bank Credit Card
Axis Bank Freecharge Credit Card
Axis Bank MY Zone Credit Card
Axis Bank Neo Credit Card
Axis Bank Vistara Credit Card
Axis Bank Vistara Signature Credit Card
Axis Bank Vistara Infinite Credit Card
Axis Bank Privilege Credit Card
Miles and More Axis Bank Credit Card
Axis Bank Select Credit Card
Axis Bank Pride Platinum Credit Card
Axis Bank Pride Signature Credit Card
Axis Bank MY Zone Easy Credit Card
Axis Bank Insta Easy Credit Card
Axis Bank Signature Credit Card with Lifestyle Benefits
Platinum Credit Card
Titanium Smart Traveler Credit Card
Axis Bank My Wings Credit Card
```